# jQuery drag n' drop won't let me drag outside of a scrollable div?

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, scroll

ok i've got a table with drag and drop classes in a div that has it's overflow set to "auto", this allows me to hide part of a schedule and only puts a scroll bar on the bottom. however, i just created some droppable elements outside of the scrollable div and my draggable elements can't leave the scrollable div. any ideas?

Comment: Source code would be very handy http://gist.github.com/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Set your draggable to helper: 'clone' and appendTo: 'body' (or whatever parent container you want to constrain to.)

Comment: I had the same problem a while ago and this fixed it. The only catch is you have to use 'clone' (meaning you're duplicating the element and not dragging the original element along).

Comment: that helped, but now, whenever i try to drop my draggable on the new drop zones, the hidden drops still catch the draggable even though the new drop is in front of the hidden ones? is there any way to give a certain drop priority? i saw a parameter of "greedy" for droppables but i'm not sure what it is or if thats even what i need. any more ideas?